# how to return a function value that is in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, tkinter

I have a tkinter project that try to make unknown number of Entry and get their value after a button clicked! I tried many ways, but I can not return the Entry value after declared! Here is my approach:

```
from tkinter import Entry, Tk, Button

l = [50]


def entry(x, y):
    global data
    e = Entry()
    e.place(x=x, y=y, height=20, width=100)
    data = e.get()
    return data


def loop():
    n = 0
    s = l[0]
    for_x = 10
    for_y = 10
    global en
    en = dict()
    while True:
        if n == s:
            break
        else:
            en[n] = entry(for_x, for_y)
            n = n + 1
            if for_y >= 400:
                for_x = for_x + 110
                for_y = 10
                print("110")
            else:
                for_y = for_y + 30
                print("30")
            print("finally")


root = Tk()

root.minsize(500, 500)

loop()


def dp():
    print(en)


b = Button(command=dp)
b.place(x=480, y=400)
root.mainloop()
```

The dictionary however do show the values, but only values that was at time of widget declaration! I want to get the value of it after declaration! Any ideas?

Comment: You never again refer to the global `data`; why create it at all? `entry` can just return `e.get()`, and that value gets assigned to `en[n]`.

Comment: Likewise, it's not clear why `l` is a global variable, rather than `loop` taking the list (or just the only element in that list) as an argument.

Comment: Finally, `en` is just an array of values held by the `Entry` objects *when they are first created*. You need to store the `Entry` objects themselves and call each one's `get` method when the button is clicked.

Comment: That is my problem! I do not know on second time, how to store Entry objects! Also I was making the code for unknown number and L is used for testing! I know it need a lot of cleaning, but its just for solving problem!

Comment: `entry` should just return `e`, not `e.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running `e.get` during the entry box creation.  You need to run `e.get()` in connection with some other event.  You also should return the Entry object instead of returning the data for example:

```
def entry(x, y):
    e = Entry()
    e.place(x=x, y=y, height=20, width=100)
    return e

def loop():
    n = 0
    s = l[0]
    for_x = 10
    for_y = 10

    global entry_list

    entry_list = []  # Used to store all of the entry widgets you make

    while True:
        if n == s:
            break
        else:
            entry_list.append(entry(for_x, for_y)) # Adds a new entry widget to the list
            n = n + 1
            if for_y >= 400:
                for_x = for_x + 110
                for_y = 10
                print("110")
            else:
                for_y = for_y + 30
                print("30")
            print("finally")

def dp():
    # Get the value of each entry box
    en = []
    for e in entry_list:
        en.append(e.get())
    print(en)
```